# Height div 100% with a padding

Tags: css, html, height

I have a setup requiring a div filling 100% of the screen with a margin of 10px. Inside that, there is a navigation pane at the top followed by a content div below with a padding and an inner content dive with a padding. However, using the 100% height of parent and then adding a margin/padding stretches the div to 100% + margin + padding. Is there a fix for this? I noticed the absolute positioning trick, but that messes up the flow of the other divs if I absolutely position my content div. It also makes the resizing and flow non-liquid. Any way to keep those things and still achieve my goal, preferrably with CSS and not javascript?

Code Below:

ASPX

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="navigation">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="inner">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:Black;
}
#wrapper
{
    height:100%;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:Blue;
}
#navigation
{
    height:100px;
    background-color:Green;   
}
#content
{
    height:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:Orange;
}
#inner
{  
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:Lime;
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting margin on `wrapper` can you set `padding` on body?

Comment: @mrtsherman It still stretches the body element larger than the html parent element.

Comment: Try setting the margin of the wrapper as a %

Comment: Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/azrXw/

Answer (score 17):

You can try adding `box-sizing:border-box` onto any elements which you want to have 100% height and padding at the same time.

Works in IE8+ and the good browsers, so browser support is actually quite good

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: I wish. I'm developing for IE7. I neglected to mention that above. Thank you though. If I was in a better environment, that would work golden.

Comment: This is great. I didn't realize box-sizing:border-box was supported in IE8. I'm extremely tired of the illogical default box modal and the amount of wrapper DIVs needed to accomplish seemingly simple things. I'll be applying this box modal to all elements from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things...

1) changing the height of the wrapper, navigation, content and inner to something like 98%.

2) try adding a transparent 1px solid border to the wrapper and other elements.  This often shifts the margin to margin relationship of elements.

Hope this helps

Comment: 98% will work if you put the padding in % too. Otherwise, you can be sure that someone will find a situation where this won't work reliably!

Comment: 1) Still produces offset/stretching issues, even when using padding as a %.
2) The border also adds to the stretch effect, so essentially the same issue as margin/padding.